# Ideas for refactoring some duplicated code in peer angularjs controllers for managing $intervals

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a small SPA that displays several tabs.  Each tab displays operational status information about the application it's associated with.  The controllers for each tab create $interval objects that make AJAX calls to the server to get status info.

To be a good citizen, I concluded that when one tab is visible, the $intervals for the other tabs should be disabled so that they don't make the AJAX calls.  The $interval for another tab/controller would be enabled when that tab is selected.

In the HTML, each of my "tab" elements has attributes like the following:

```
select="selected()" deselect="deselected()"
```

In the controller associated with each tab, I defined those methods, and they create and cancel, respectively, the $interval associated with that tab.  In one of the tabs, I have a controller for the tab, but it has an accordion with two entries, and I use "$broadcast" so that the accordion entries can manage their own $intervals.

What I don't like is that I have a handful of little methods that are almost duplicated in every controller.  Each controller has a "selected" and "deselected" method, and all the components that manage their own $interval have "startInterval" and "cancelInterval" methods.  In most of the tabs, all four of those are in the controller for the tab.  For the one tab that uses "$broadcast", I have the "selected" and "deselected" methods in the tab controller, and the "startInterval" and "cancelInterval" methods in the accordion controllers.

I wish I could define "selected" and "deselected" in the parent controller of all the tabs, but make it so that those methods "call into" the associated tab controller by adding some small "registration" code in the html for the tab.

However, it's possible that saving duplication in the controller will end up with some strange looking code in the HTML.

Any ideas for how to do this better?

Comment: You can put the code in a run block or wrap the code in a mainCtrl or set up a parent controller (better imo you avoid global state)

Answer (score 4):

What I do is add a helper service that configures my controller.  Something like this:

```
angular.module('myModule').service("controllerHelper", function() {

  this.configController = function(controller) {
    controller.oneCommonMethod = function() {/*Some common code*/};
    controller.twoCommonMethod = function() {/*Some more common code*/};
  }

});

angular.module('myModule').controller("myController", function($scope, controllerHelper) {

  controllerHelper.configController(this);

});
```

You can also share state between the controller that call this helper service to accomplish what you want.

Comment: If you need some config in a service,provider could be a better option

Comment: @Whisher I think you are missing the point of Geoff's example service.

Answer (score 1):

Just to play around with @Geoff Genz code

```
angular.module('app', [])
                .service("controllerHelper", function() {
                    this.configController = function(scope) {
                            scope.test = 'My test';
                    }
                })
               .controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,controllerHelper){
                    controllerHelper.configController($scope);
               });
```

If for instance you have got a crud needs a datepicker config
you can exploit this code

**Update**

Imo the code above go against oop encapsulation principle

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't quite use this advice directly, but I imagine my solution has some of this feel.

I changed my HTML for each to the following:

```
select="selected(this)" deselect="deselected(this)"
```

I then defined an app-wide controller with these elements:

```
$scope.tabsOpened   = {};

$scope.deselected   =
    function(ctrl) {
        ctrl.tabClosed();
        delete $scope.tabsOpened[ctrl];
    };
$scope.selected     =
    function(ctrl) {
        ctrl.tabOpened();
        $scope.tabsOpened[ctrl] = ctrl;
    };

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    for (var ctrl in tabsOpened) {
        if ($scope.tabsOpened.hasOwnProperty(ctrl))
            ctrl.tabClosed();
    }
});
```

In the controller for each tab I defined "tabOpened" and "tabClosed" functions in each scope.  That leaves it up to each tab's controller to do its setup and cleanup.  Notice that I also handle the $destroy event in the top controller, and tell each tab to clean up.